# Using a Firebase session cookie to authenticate with Firebase Realtime DB REST API

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Authenticating a realtime DB REST request with an idToken works but authenticating the same request with a session cookie generated from that idToken does not.

```
// Successfully authenticates and returns JSON
axios.get("https://my-project.firebaseio.com/path/to/data.json?auth=<idToken>")


getAuth().createSessionCookie(idToken, { expiresIn })
    .then(
        (sessionCookie) => {
            // fails with 401 permission denied
            axios.get("https://my-project.firebaseio.com/path/to/data.json?auth=<sessionToken>")
        }
    )
```